# How can I add admin authentication to all pages?

Tags: redirect, authentication

I already have implemented admin login authentications to site. Whenever admin visits dashboard he is asked to put a log in credentials.

But when you visit some page from admin panel lets say    .../admin/addblog.php  in such cases it doesn't ask for authentication.

How can I redirect to the admin login page and once authenticated then direct back to the origional page again

Comment: What you are asking about is "Authorization" depending on the framework you are using you can search for ways to achieve that.
Try to provide  [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex) and add the related tags to the technology you're using

Comment: When the user logs in, set a session variable. on every page, include a simple check to see if the session variable is set. If not, simply redirect. I'm assuming you're not using a framework.

Comment: You should do a web search on this. Clearly you cannot be the first person to run into this problem. Every framework has already solved it. If you use a framework, look up how that framework handles it.  If you don't use a framework, consider using one, or you will reinvent a lot of wheels.

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple way to do this, just add the "login_url" parameter to @login_required and if the user is not login he will be redirected to the login page. You can find it [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/default/)

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required(login_url='/accounts/login/')
def my_view(request):
    ...
```